# why am I getting fontconfig errors when running spyder?

Tags: fonts, spyder

```
(dst) kashif@stats:~/intel/intelpython2/envs/dst/etc/fonts$ ls
conf.d  fonts.conf
```

So my `fonts.conf` file clearly exists. However, when I run spyder, I get this error:

```
(dst) kashif@stats:~$ Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
```

I've tried `export FONTCONFIG_PATH=/etc/fonts` but that didn't work. I still get this error message. What is going on  here?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
export FONTCONFIG_PATH=$CONDA_PATH/etc/fonts/
```

Comment: You really should explain: **what** this does and **how** it solves the problem.